# Python assign value to multiple list elements

Tags: python, list, syntax

I am starting maintenance on some code that assigns values to variables in this manner:

```py
[thing_filenames, thing_list]=Load_Things(bunch_of_things)
```

I haven't seen values assigned to variables with brackets on the left side. Can someone please provide a pointer for where I can start to understand this statement?

Comment: Did you look at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements?

Comment: Load_Things looks like a function, so I'd look at def Load_Things(): and see what it returns.

Comment: From the doc: 'Assignment of an object to a target list, **optionally enclosed in parentheses or square brackets**, [...]'

Comment: The brackets can actually be omitted, but this is an example of *iterable unpacking*. I've gone ahead and closed this as a duplicate, but the accepted answer to that duplicate target will give you a ton of information about this and similar syntactical constructs in Python.

Comment: thanks; I understand now that I was asking an extremely basic question

Answer (score 1):

It is normal unpacking of variables

```py
[cat, dog] = ('Meow', 'Wuf')

print(cat) # 'Meow'
print(dog) # 'Wuf'
```

`Load_Things(bunch_of_things)` is a `class` or `function` that returns results that can be unpacked as I shown above.

Answer (score 0):

The brackets are only there to represent a group of variables. An equally valid line of code would be:

```
thing_filenames, thing_list = Load_Things(bunch_of_things)
```

The function `Load_Things()` most likely returns two values, which are then assigned to those two variables on one single line. Diving into Load_Things() will give you a better idea of what those variables represent in the code.

For example:

```
[item1, item2] = 1, 2
item3, item4 = 3, 4

print(item1, item2, item3, item4)
# Output: 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks, everyone. This is just was I was looking for.